# Turn Python Game in local lan multiplayer game

Tags: python, networking, turtle-graphics

i make a game called "Pong" in python and turtle(module) and i want to make it a local LAN multiplayer game.

can someone tell me how can i do it.

i want to make it a local host like game so that me and my brother can play.

Comment: You may want to edit your tags. They make no sense

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that .

Answer (score 0):

You'll achieve this by using sockets.

As a start, you'll need to make a `Server` script which will handle the game events.
Also, you'll need a `client` script that will display the game to the player & take the user's input + send them to the Server.
The server will be responsible for the synchronization of the game in both clients.
You can run the server script in your PC then connect using the client script from both computers to the server.

Here is a [link](https://gafferongames.com/post/what_every_programmer_needs_to_know_about_game_networking/) ("What every programmer needs to know about Game Networking") for further details.

EDIT:
I found [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2614-multiplayer-game-programming-for-teens-with-python-part-1) tutorial to create a simple 2-player game using `PyGame` and `PodSixNet`.
The first part is creating the Client side of the game.
The second part is creating the Server side & adding the game logic.
It may be a good start if you're interested.

Comment: it does not help me :( ,  i am a beginner and i need a tutorial is there any tutorial in the world ?.

Comment: A network game is usually not something a beginner tries to make. At the very least you will need a server script, client script, an understanding of ports, IP addresses, and asynchronous programming. Do you want to put that amount of effort into it?

Comment: I've added a link for a tutorial but it's using PyGame & PodSixNet.